# Prove $n^7$ - n is divisible by 42 for all n.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This question is pulled from a number theory practice set that did not provide an answer key. Link: [https://www.math.toronto.edu/~herzig/putnam_nt_oct07.pdf](https://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Eherzig/putnam_nt_oct07.pdf)

My reasoning is to prove that $n^7$ - n is divisible by 2,3, and 7 because they are the prime factors of 42. I've proven divisibility by 2, but I cannot prove divisibility by 3 or 7.

Please let me know if this is the right path, and any ideas are welcomed proving divisibility by 3 or 7.

Comment: $ n^7-n=n(n^6-1)=n(n^3+1)(n^3-1)=n(n+1)(n^2-n+1)(n-1)(n^2+n+1)$

Comment: Hints: By Fermat's little theorem, $n^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and $n^7 \equiv n \bmod 7$

Comment: Another duplicate post is [Prove that $n^7$ = n(mod 42)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1873784/602049).

Comment: @KeithBackman.  Only if $\gcd(n,3)=1$.  BUt in general. Either $p|n$ (and so $p|n^k-n$) or $n^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod p$.  And if $n^{p-1}\equiv 1$ then $n^{k{p-1}} \equiv 1\pmod p$ and $n^{k{p-1} + 1} \equiv n \pmod p$.  And for $p = 2,3,7$ wehave $6(2-1)+ 1=3(3-1) + 1 = 1(7-1) + 1 = 7$ so we have $n^7-n \equiv 0 \pmod{2,3,7}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use  *Euler-Fermat*:

For any prime $p$, one has $\;n^p\equiv n\mod p$.

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242)